# Php convert string into JSON or an Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Can anyone please help me for converting the string into an Array or JSON as well? Please take look on the text sample below;

```
{
    "account_id": "dfdfdf",
    "email": "mail-noreply@google.com",
    "id": "dfdfdf",
    "name": "Gmail Team",
    "object": "contact",
    "phone_numbers": []
},
{
    "account_id": "dfdf",
    "email": "saaddfsdfsdsfsdf@gmail.com",
    "id": "dfdf",
    "name": "Ab",
    "object": "contact",
    "phone_numbers": []
},
{
    "account_id": "dfdf",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "id": "dfdfdf",
    "name": "xyz",
    "object": "contact",
    "phone_numbers": []
},
```

I have tried

```
preg_match_all("/\{([^\)]*)\},/", $stream[0], $aMatches);
```

But it doesn't return anything. I also have tried json_decode, json_encode but could not find any success on it.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @fusion3k Already tried. This is string and it results in null

Comment: Please provide a link to **real** string. With your example, below provided answer is fine.

Comment: thanks for the support @fusion3k . I agree, the string given is not the same as what he is seeing if the problem persists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The goal is to turn it into appropriate JSON format so that you can use `json_decode`. Ill break it down in steps:

1. remove all `\n` characters:

   ```
   $string = str_replace('\n', '', $string);
   ```
2. remove last comma

   ```
   $string = rtrim($string, ',');
   ```
3. add brackets

   ```
   $string = "[" . trim($string) . "]";
   ```
4. turn it into PHP array:

   ```
   $json = json_decode($string, true);
   ```

**Result:**

```
$string = ''; //your string
$string = str_replace('\n', '', $string);
$string = rtrim($string, ',');
$string = "[" . trim($string) . "]";
$json = json_decode($string, true);
var_dump($json);
```

**Output:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'account_id' => string '43z95ujithllc32fn02u8ynef' (length=25)
      'email' => string 'mail-noreply@google.com' (length=23)
      'id' => string '955xl0q3h9qe0sc11so8cojo2' (length=25)
      'name' => string 'Gmail Team' (length=10)
      'object' => string 'contact' (length=7)
      'phone_numbers' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'account_id' => string '43z95ujithllc32fn02u8ynef' (length=25)
      'email' => string 'test-email1@gmail.com' (length=21)
      'id' => string '3u4e6i9ka3e7ad4km90nip73u' (length=25)
      'name' => string 'Test Account 1' (length=14)
      'object' => string 'contact' (length=7)
      'phone_numbers' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  2 => 
    array (size=6)
      'account_id' => string '43z95ujithllc32fn02u8ynef' (length=25)
      'email' => string 'test-email@gmail.com' (length=20)
      'id' => string 'bt3lphmp0g14y82zelpcf0w0r' (length=25)
      'name' => string 'Test Account' (length=12)
      'object' => string 'contact' (length=7)
      'phone_numbers' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Comment: then you are not providing all the string in your original post.

Comment: how is your string formed? Where are you getting the string from?

Comment: It is string response from a third party API Nylas. I am posting exactly what I am having. I want array where data between `{` and `},` can be get as internal array

Comment: I see that you updated your string but that is very different than your original string. Before you had `\n` characters... what happened to them?

Comment: in that case, do the same as my answer, but dont follow step 1.